# materialized view versus tables for star model construction(oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, business-intelligence

Good afternoon friends,

I have some queries regarding oracle and what would be better to build star models (BI models).

which would be better to build dimensions and fact tables, materialized views or tables?
In order to have the best performance, I can think of some differences between materialized views and tables.

ADVANTAGE of Materialized Views:

VMs are easy to develop.
incremental load management is easy, it does not need much development.

DISADVANTAGE of materialized views:

for very large data volumes, it seems to me that they do not support partitioning.

I would appreciate any help or point of view that you would recommend to me, or if someone developed their entire star model with materialized views, what suggestions could they provide.

what is not clear to me is, although I can make the model with tables and materialized views, at what time or what would be the factor that determines the use of one or the other.
Thanks a lot,

Comment: Materialized views are projections of tables. They hold data redundancy for fast querying. Tables should store the actual data.

Comment: Also, didn't Oracle 11 reach end of life already?

Comment: no, until oracle 18 is still valid.

Comment: Also take note that Mat views comes with the price of maintenance overhead. They have additional objects associated with them and refresh at times gets stuck which needs to be looked into. Overall, it all comes under maintenance. So look at the trade off and decide. Best is to use mat view only for facts which come from result of multiple joins and can be complex and there are queries from those facts quite often. I don't see any reason why will you use materialized view for dimensions unless those dimensions are derived by complex queries from other tables, which should not be the case.

Comment: Performance will be the same, because materialized view consists of a physical table (it also contains `on prebuilt table` clause, as you may notice). They may provide an advantage of fast refresh but this scenario is a rare case for DWH, where it may be much faster to perform partition-wise recalculation for fact tables and may reqire complex logic including before and after versions for change-tracking for dimension tables. In one of our project we used MVs to flatten a hierarchy, because it was a single query that "just needs to be executed" with no parameters

Comment: Extended support for Oracle 11gR2 ended in Dec. 2020. Support for Oracle 18c ended in June 2021. After next month (July 2022), only 19c will be in active support. https://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lsp-tech-chart-069290.pdf

Comment: what is not clear to me is, although I can make the model with tables and materialized views, at what time or what would be the factor that determines the use of one or the other.